# Run JavaScript function in phonegap ios application in background.

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, timer, phonegap-plugins

I am working in phonegap ios application. In my application I'm using increment timer and decrement timer using javascript setTimeout function. When I press the menu button in my iPhone the timer function paused its count. When I reopen its start the counting from end. So anyone help me to solve this problem. How to run phonegap ios application javascript function in background.

Answer (score 0):

Timers run on main thread. So when application goes into background they can not run. What you can do is to save the timer count and time when application goes into background. When application comes into foreground, take the difference of time and and it to you count.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok how to find that the app is  in active state after background

Comment: Why do you want to know it?

Comment: Use the `pause` and `resume` events for this.  Example: `document.addEventListener('pause', app.devicePause, false);`

Answer (score 0):

you can get source code as well as demo for timer from this link

use the blow code it implement the timer

```
var count = 0;
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++count);
});
timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
```

There are many other options also which you can explore. For example

```
var Example1 = new (function() {

// Stopwatch element on the page
var $stopwatch;

// Timer speed in milliseconds
var incrementTime = 70;

// Current timer position in milliseconds
var currentTime = 0;

// Start the timer
$(function() {
    $stopwatch = $('#stopwatch');
    Example1.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);  
});

// Output time and increment
function updateTimer() {
    var timeString = formatTime(currentTime);
    $stopwatch.html(timeString);
    currentTime += incrementTime;
}

// Reset timer
this.resetStopwatch = function() {
    currentTime = 0;
    Example1.Timer.stop().once();
};

});
```

Hope this helps.!